# Stopping Execution of Linkbutton when Ajax-Call failed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, ajax, postback

I have a LinkButton which only needs to postback when the Ajax-Call inside the delete function fails. 
The ajax-call calls a Webmethod which throws an exception if the deletion of the rows failed for some reason. 
When i throw the exception the ajax call reaches the "error"-branch (as expected). But when the "deleteSelectedRows" function returns false, the postback is not being stopped.
How can i archieve this?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return deleteSelectedRows()" ></asp:LinkButton>

//the jquery code
function deleteSelectedRows() {
        //get selected rows
        var selectedRows = ... getting ids ...

        var postData = "{ 'IDs':'" + selectedRows + "'}";
        var url = "WebMethods.aspx/DeleteRows";
        var status= jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                return true;//continue postback
            },
            error: function (err) {
                jQuery.jGrowl('Fehler: Auftragspositionen konnten nicht gelöscht werden! Möglicherweise existieren bereits Transaktionen zu dieser Auftragsposition.');
                //e.preventDefault();
                return false;//stop postback
            }
        });
        return status.status == 200;//true when delete worked, false otherwise
    }
```

EDIT: This works when i use a asp:Button instead of asp:Linkbutton... but i dont have a clue why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i solved it: 
the problem was due to the following code which i used to stop execution of links if they are disabled (maybe this is useful for someone else too, so i post it here):

```
jQuery('.btn[onclick]').each(function () {
    //override onclick so i can check if the link is disabled before execution
    jQuery(this).data('onclick', this.onclick);

    this.onclick = function (event) {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('aspNetDisabled')) { //disabled link
            return false;//prevent execution
        };

        //execute link
        jQuery(this).data('onclick').call(this, event || window.event);
    };
});
```

i changed this to, and now its working:

```
jQuery('.btn[onclick]').each(function () {
    //override onclick so i can check if the link is disabled before execution
    jQuery(this).data('onclick', this.onclick);

    this.onclick = function (event) {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('aspNetDisabled')) { //disabled link
            return false;//prevent execution
        };

        //execute link
        var boolVal = jQuery(this).data('onclick').call(this, event || window.event);
        return boolVal;
    };
});
```

i have to admit, that the question couldnt be solved with the information i provided!